# Async UI update, concurrency - android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, concurrency

I have an Thread running and i set a listener to know when the job is done, in my listener i have a method `onCompleted` which returns me some data i use to update my `UI` elements.
Some times i get NPEs, i think because the user changes `Activity` or something similar.

I tried using `NULL` checks but it is pretty annoying to do every time.

Now i want to ask if somebody knows an easy way to avoid this instead of place null checks into my code?

Comment: If you are certain that its because of activity change, you can set a flag in `onPause()`, `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`, but, what's wrong with checking a null value?

Comment: if u need to `consume and specifically update the UI` the response returned by your background process. Then you should run a check `onDestroy()` of your activity that your background process is running or not, if it's running then cancel the background process `ultimately u won't run into NPEs`, this can easily be achieved using `Async Task` classs in Android.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at AsyncTask class which is specially designed to work with Activity and UI-thread.